# Arbitrary attributes error with has_one association and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to build a basic shopping cart for a Rails app I'm working on.

Nothing special,
- the shopping cart has many line_items
- each line_item has_one product associated and a quantity with it

```
 class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :line_items
   has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
 end

 class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :quantity, :product

   belongs_to :cart
   has_one :product
 end
```

I'm trying to use RSpec to test this association, but i'm doing something wrong as I'm getting an error that says: `DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute 'line_item_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated`, and I'm not sure why.

In my factories.rb file I'm defining the line_item factory as follows:

```
factory :line_item do
  quantity { Random.rand(1..5) }
  product
end

factory :cart do
  factory :cart_with_two_line_items do
    ignore do
      line_item_count 2
    end

    after(:create) do |cart, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:line_item, evaluator.line_item_count, cart_id: cart) # < 104
    end
  end
end
```

Any pointers where I'm going wrong, it's probably something basic, but I'm still quite new to Rspec. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: line_item_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe LineItem do
before do
  @line_item = FactoryGirl.create(:line_item)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to declare the association in the Product model.

```
class Product < Activerecord::Base
  belongs_to :line_item
```

belongs_to will expect that your products table has a column :line_item_id. Have you run your migration and modified the models?

Comment: Yes, I think that is it! How silly of me. This is possibly a daft question, but to help my understanding - as I usually only work in the view and controller layers, so models are still fairly new to me - why is it necessary to have that counterpart on the Product model? Is that always the case with associations, or are there situations where it's one way?

Comment: ...hmmm turns out that wasn't it. As I'm still getting the notifications:

`DEPRECATION WARNING: You're trying to create an attribute 'line_item_id'. Writing arbitrary attributes on a model is deprecated. Please just use 'attr_writer' etc. (called from block (4 levels) in <top (required)> at /code/spec/factories.rb:104)`

Comment: what code the line 104 in this file has? Please paste the relevant code around it with some comment indicating line 104.

Comment: Hi @Salil, thanks for your continued help. I've highlighted line 104, you might need to scroll right to see it though. I also get the error for line 5 of line_item_spec.rb where the Factory is created, I've also added this line. Apologies for not adding these sooner.

Comment: Have you run your migration after modifying Product? belongs_to will expect that your products table has a column :line_item_id.

Comment: Had to do that, and modify the migration too, then for some reason I also had to drop and run db:migrate (db:setup wasn't recognising the change, not sure why) and then after running db:test:prepare and restarting guard, it started to work... what a faff. Anyway, sorted now, many thanks for all your help!

Comment: db:migrate will modify only the development database. Yes, db:test:prepare is the one which builds the test database. So, no wonder it did the trick. :)